# In the Aharanov-Bohm experiment, how are we sure that the electrons do not ever enter regions with $\vec B\neq 0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, aharonov-bohm

In the Aharanov-Bohm experiment, we say that the electron passes through a region where the magnetic field $\vec B=0$ but the vector potential $\vec A\neq 0$. The electron never passes through the region where $\vec B\neq 0$ i.e. through the interior of the solenoid. But how can we be sure of that?  Because the electron wavefunctions are smeared out. How can we be sure that the tails of the electron wavefunction do not penetrate the interior of the solenoid?

Answer (score 1):

We can hypothesize an infinite potential barrier around the solenoid. The Aharonov Bohm effect can be shown theoretically all the same.
We can also hypothesize the solenoid to be infinitely thin. The area of the solenoid does not affect the Aharonov Bohm effect.